# Oraclize_ Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Tags: go-ethereum, oracles

When i am going to deploy this code its give error:The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.

Solidity CODE:

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract OraclizeFetch is usingOraclize{

```
string public ETHXBT;

event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
event price(string price);


function OraclizeFetch() payable{
    oraclize_setProof(proofType_TLSNotary | proofStorage_IPFS);
    update();
}

function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result, bytes proof) {
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
    ETHXBT = result;
    price(ETHXBT);
    update();
}

function update() payable {
    if (oraclize.getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
        newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
    } else {
        newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
        oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0");
    }
}
```

}

My genesis.json file:

{
    "nonce": "0xdeadbeefdeadbeef",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x0",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
    "alloc": {

```
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Thomas from Oraclize here, on what network are you trying to run this on? Is it a private testnet or what else?

Comment: Hi Thomas,We are using private network.

Comment: if you want to use Oraclize within a private chain context, you need to set up and execute the Oraclize [ethereum-bridge](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge) there. You will find instructions in that repository. If you need any further assistance, feel free to come to our [dedicated gitter support channel](http://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example of your code, testable with Oraclize in a browser:

http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.9+commit.364da425.js&optimize=undefined&gist=a5e9d93dbd1fd5beb9fe1d7012834eba

Some issues were that you were trying to call oraclize through `oraclize.getPrice` before that variable was even initialized and set. To do this you need to either pre-initialize it somehow, one way to pre-initialize is calling `oraclize_setProof(proofType_NONE)` to get results without proofs, or use the internal `getPrice` function provided by Oraclize in the API which is `oraclize_getPrice`.

Secondly, in another iteration of the contract you asked us about, you were setting the gas to include to 50M, yet you weren't doing a price check of that allotted gas amount, and it's a very high and unrealistic gas cost amount especially for this query, which will cost several ether with such a high gas amount.

This contract should work fine on your privatenet, just ensure the OAR is set correctly for it.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but the contract is a bit more complicated. The thing is that everything works, and Truffle migrates successfully when I'm commenting the __callback() function. Do you know anything about that?